# Why is this Constructor Method not valid?

Tags: javascript, function, constructor

Why is this giving me an error: "Uncaught TypeError: Parent.child is not a function"

```js
function Parent () {
 this.child = (num) => {
  console.log(num);
 }
}

Parent.child(4);
```

Comment: You have to use `new`. When you say constructor, its always associated with an instance. Try `new Person().child(4)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this way

```js
     function Parent () {
     this.child = (num) => {
      console.log(num);
     }
    }
    
    const  p = new Parent();
    p.child(4);
```